# Scrapy: crawlspider not generating all links in nested callbacks

Tags: python, scrapy, yield

I have written a scrapy crawlspider to crawl a site with a structure like category page > type page > list page > item page. On the category page there are many categories of machines each of which has a type page with lots of types, each of the different types has a list of items, then finally each machine has a page with info about it.

My spider has a rule to get from the home page to the category page where I define the callback parsecatpage, this generates an item, grabs the category and yields a new request for each category on the page. I pass the item and the category name with request.meta and specify the callback is parsetype page.

Parsetypepage gets the item from response.meta then yields requests for each type and passes the item, and the concatenation of category and type along with it in the request.meta. The callback is parsemachinelist.

Parsemachinelist gets the item from response.meta then yields requests for each item on the list and passes the item, category/type, description via request.meta to the final callback, parsemachine. This gets the meta attributes and populates all the fields in the item using the info on the page and the info that was passed from the previous pages and finally yields an item.

If I limit this to a single category and type (with for example `contains[@href, "filter=c:Grinders"]` and `contains[@href, "filter=t:Disc+-+Horizontal%2C+Single+End"]`) then it works and there is a machine item for each machine on the final page. The problem is that once I allow the spider to scrapy all the categories and all the types it only returns scrapy items for the machines on the first of the final pages it gets to and once it has done that the spider is finished and doesn't get the other categories etc.

Here is the (anonymous) code

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from myspider.items import MachineItem
import urlparse


class MachineSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/index.php']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=('example.com'),allow=('12\.html'),unique=True),callback='parsecatpage'),
        )

    def parsecatpage(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
#this works, next line doesn't   categories = hxs.select('//a[contains(@href, "filter=c:Grinders")]')  
        categories = hxs.select('//a[contains(@href, "filter=c:Grinders") or contains(@href, "filter=c:Lathes")]')
        for cat in categories:
            item = MachineItem()
            req = Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url,''.join(cat.select("@href").extract()).strip()),callback=self.parsetypepage)
            req.meta['item'] = item
            req.meta['machinecategory'] = ''.join(cat.select("./text()").extract())
            yield req

    def parsetypepage(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
#this works, next line doesn't   types = hxs.select('//a[contains(@href, "filter=t:Disc+-+Horizontal%2C+Single+End")]')
        types = hxs.select('//a[contains(@href, "filter=t:Disc+-+Horizontal%2C+Single+End") or contains(@href, "filter=t:Lathe%2C+Production")]')
        for typ in types:
            item = response.meta['item']
            req = Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url,''.join(typ.select("@href").extract()).strip()),callback=self.parsemachinelist)
            req.meta['item'] = item
            req.meta['machinecategory'] = ': '.join([response.meta['machinecategory'],''.join(typ.select("./text()").extract())])
            yield req

    def parsemachinelist(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for row in hxs.select('//tr[contains(td/a/@href, "action=searchdet")]'):
            item = response.meta['item']
            req = Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url,''.join(row.select('./td/a[contains(@href,"action=searchdet")]/@href').extract()).strip()),callback=self.parsemachine)
            print urlparse.urljoin(response.url,''.join(row.select('./td/a[contains(@href,"action=searchdet")]/@href').extract()).strip())
            req.meta['item'] = item
            req.meta['descr'] = row.select('./td/div/text()').extract()
            req.meta['machinecategory'] = response.meta['machinecategory']
            yield req

    def parsemachine(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['machinecategory'] = response.meta['machinecategory']
        item['comp_name'] = 'Name'
        item['description'] = response.meta['descr']
        item['makemodel'] = ' '.join([''.join(hxs.select('//table/tr[contains(td/strong/text(), "Make")]/td/text()').extract()),''.join(hxs.select('//table/tr[contains(td/strong/text(), "Model")]/td/text()').extract())])
        item['capacity'] = hxs.select('//tr[contains(td/strong/text(), "Capacity")]/td/text()').extract()
        relative_image_url = hxs.select('//img[contains(@src, "custom/modules/images")]/@src')[0].extract()
        abs_image_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, relative_image_url.strip())
        item['image_urls'] = [abs_image_url]
        yield item

SPIDER = MachineSpider()
```

So for example the spider will find Grinders on the category page and go to the Grinder type page where it will find the Disc Horizontal Single End type, then it will go to that page and find the list of machines and go to each machines page and finally there will be an item for each machine. If you try and go to Grinders and Lathes though it will run through the Grinders fine then it will crawl the Lathes and Lathes type pages and stop there without generating the requests for the Lathes list page and the final Lathes pages.

Can anyone help with this? Why isn't the spider getting to the second (or third etc.) machine list page once there is more than one category of machine?

Sorry for the epic post, just trying to explain the problem!!

Thanks!!

Comment: If you find any useful answers/questions on this site, please upvote them

Answer (score 2):

You should print the url of the request, to be sure it's ok. Also you can try this version:

```
def parsecatpage(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    categories = hxs.select('//a[contains(@href, "filter=c:Grinders") or contains(@href, "filter=c:Lathes")]')
    for cat in categories:
        item = MachineItem()
        cat_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, cat.select("./@href").extract()[0])
        print 'url:', cat_url # to see what's there
        cat_name = cat.select("./text()").extract()[0]
        req = Request(cat_url, callback=self.parsetypepage, meta={'item': item, 'machinecategory': cat_name})
        yield req
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the neater use of meta in request! I have put print statements in all the callbacks to see what happens. I can see the url for the Grinders page and the Lathes page in parsecatpage then they are crawled, then I can see the urls for the type of Grinder and type of Lathe in parsetypepage then they are crawled. After that in parsemachinelist I see the urls for the machines listed on the Lathes list page which are crawled and scraped but the urls from the Grinders list page are not printed, crawled or scraped. Why not?

Comment: if it's not printed, then either urls are not extracted or the callback is not called. put a print in the beginning of the callback, and do `print hxs.select('//a[...]/@href').extract()` before the loop

Comment: I also checked with scrapy shell and the url of the Grinders list page that the xpath is valid, it does return the correct urls in the shell but not when it is run in the spider. I think it is something to do with the order of the requests, sometimes it returns items for the Grinder machines but doesn't do the Lathes so it seems like after it has got to the end of the first list of machines it finishes without going back for the others.

Comment: Sorry, cannot help. I think the problem is somewhere in logic, and you have to debug it.

Comment: I have added print statements and the callback is called both times but the xpath is empty the second time. I have checked that the xpath is correct as if you change the `contains[...]` filter to Lathes only or Grinders only it works. Do you know why an xpath would only extract the rows in the list the first time a callback is called? I appreciate the help with this!

Comment: Usually this happens, because you get not the page you expected. Check the html source in both cases - i believe second time you get a different type of page, that's why xpath query doesn't find what you need

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the website is set up so that moving from the category to type page (and the following pages) occurs via filtering the results that are shown. This means that if the requests are performed depth first to the bottom of the query then it works (i.e. choose a category, then get all the types of that category, then get all the machines in each type then scrape the page of each machine) but if a request for the next type page is processed before the spider has got the urls for each machine in the first type then the urls are no longer correct and the spider reaches an incorrect page and cannot extract the info for the next step.

To solve the problem I defined a category setup callback which is called the first time only and gets a list of all categories called `categories`, then a category callback which is called from category setup which starts the crawl with a single category only using `categories.pop()`. Once the spider has got to the bottom of the nested callbacks and scraped all the machines in the list there is a callback back up to the category callback again (needed `dont_follow=True` in the `Request`) where `categories.pop()` starts the process again with the next category in the list until they are all done. This way each category is treated fully before the next is started and it works.

Thanks for your final comment, that got me thinking along the right lines and led me to the solution!